# SQL Map multiple columns to same table

Tags: sql, join, mapping

I have data where two columns `[Previous State]` and `[Next State]` contain values from the same list of States.

I have a separate table with two columns that maps these states to updated state names like so:

`State   | Mapped State |
--------+--------------+
1       | a            | 
2       | b            | 
3       | b            | 
4       | c            | 
5       | d            |`

I want to pull the `[Previous State]` and `[Next State]` in my query displaying the relative `[Mapped State]` values.

The code I have throws error when I join the state mapping table twice:

```
SELECT a.[Name], b.[Mapped State] as [Previous State Mapped], c.[Mapped State] AS [Next State Mapped] 
FROM [Raw Data] a 
JOIN [Mapping Table] b ON a.[Previous State]=b.[State] 
JOIN [Mapping Table] c ON a.[Next State]=c.[State]
```

Why is this not working? Thanks

Comment: What is the error exactly and what database system are you using ?

Comment: You should always provide the actual error in the post if you say "The code I have throws an error"...

Comment: The error is "An error occured while communicating with the data source." I am using Tableau and Microsoft SQL Server 2012. If I remove the second reference to the mapping table the query works.